# Как в java создать маccив списков

Tags: java, android, массивы, список

Есть три однотипных списка типа

```
ArrayList<AAA> a0= new ArrayList<AAA>();
ArrayList<AAA> a1= new ArrayList<AAA>();
ArrayList<AAA> a2= new ArrayList<AAA>();
```

где AAA это мой класс.

Есть переменная int Cnt; которая принимает значение 0, 1 или 2. В зависимости от этой переменной нужно использовать соответствующий список. Логично сделать массив этих списков, но что-то не пойму как. Должно быть что-то типа такого:

```
ArrayList<AAA> a[]= new ArrayList<AAA>[]{ new ArrayList<AAA>(), new ArrayList<AAA>(), new ArrayList<AAA>()};
```

Но компилятор ругается и что-то не соображу как сделать.

Comment: 1)Причем здесь ААА класс? 2) Как собираетесь использовать соответствующий список, в зависимости от значения переменной? 3) Почему это логично?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, никак: массивы в java ковариантны по типу элемента, но при этом должны проверять тип присваиваемого значения элемента во время выполнения, т.е.:

```
Object[] array = new String[10]; // массив строк является массивом объектов
array[0] = new Object();
```

компилятор пропустит, но на второй строчке во время выполнения вылетит `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`. Генерики в Java реализованы через стирание информации о типе-параметре, поэтому проверить, что присваиваемый `ArrayList` имеет типа `ArrayList<AAA>` во время выполнения нельзя, а создание массивов с таким типом элемента запрещено.

Обычно рекомендуют не связываться, и вместо массивов использовать списки. Если очень-очень хочется иметь массив, то можно объявить массив списков без указания типа:

```
ArrayList[] a = new ArrayList[] { new ArrayList<AAA>(), new ArrayList<AAA>(), new ArrayList<AAA>()};

a[1] = new ArrayList<AAA>();
AAA value = ((ArrayList<AAA>)a[1]).get( 0 );

AAA otherValue = (AAA)a[1].get( 0 ); // ммм... как в 1.4.2
```

и приводить при использовании к параметризованному типу, но компилятор заест предупреждениями про unchecked cast.

Еще можно завести свой тип, расширяющий параметризованный тип с нужным типом параметра

```
static class AAAList extends ArrayList<AAA> {}
```

и пользоваться им

```
AAAList[] a = new AAAList[] { new AAAList(), new AAAList(), new AAAList()};

a[1] = new AAAList();
AAA value = a[1].get( 0 );

ArrayList<AAA> list = a[1];
```

хотя вряд ли вам это поможет.

Comment: Вот как раз "свой тип, расширяющий параметризованный тип с нужным типом параметра" очень похож на то что мне нужно, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё получилось, как раз то что мне нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример того, что вы хотите:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(subList);
list.get(0); // доступ к subList
```

Comment: Мне нужен доступ к нужному списку не через switch/case, а через индекс массива. Что-то типа такого: a[Cnt].add(..);

Comment: @Александр Безфамильный, а вы можете сказать зачем вам это требуется? Что именно будет делать ваша программа и этот код?

Comment: Нужно для оптимизации кода. Задача классическая, есть список заказов на сегодня, есть плановые заказы на сегодня, есть заказы на завтра. Работа с ними практически одинаковая, переключаются нажатием одной из трёх кнопок. И хочется чтобы по кнопке изменялся только Cnt и посылалось сообщение на обновление экрана. Плюс в отдельном потоке получаю заказы с сервера и нужно их раскидать по нужным спискам.

Comment: @Александр Безфамильный, не берусь оценивать правильность построения вашего приложения, но я дополнил ответ кодом, который вам требуется.

Comment: Не, список списков не хочется, вот во втором ответе что-то похожее на мои желания, пойду разбираться и пробовать.

Comment: @Александр Безфамильный, я вам крайне рекомендую использовать именно список. Вы можете проверить, что работает быстрее массив или список, но я предполагаю, что разницы не будет, либо же она будет крайне незначительная. ArrayList был специально разработан для того, чтобы заменить массивы в большинстве случаев. Большинство разработчиков пользуется именно листами, а не массивами.

Comment: Если массив фиксированной длины, то в списке абсолютно нет необходимости.